# 0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid'

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#list1").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
        colModel: [
                       { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 60, sorttype: "int" },
                       { name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 90, sorttype: "date" },
                       { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 100 },
                       { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
                       { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
                       { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
                       { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150, sortable: false }
        ],
        multiselect: true,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
        pager: $('#pager1'),
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        subGrid: true,
        subGridUrl: 'Default.aspx',
        subGridModel: [{
            name: ['No', 'Item', 'Qty', 'Unit', 'Line otal'],
            width: [55, 200, 80, 80, 80]
        }
        ],
        caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
    });
    $("#list1").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager1', { del: false, add: false, edit: false }, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true });
    var mydata = [
               { id: "1", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
               { id: "2", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
               { id: "3", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
               { id: "4", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
               { id: "5", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
               { id: "6", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
               { id: "7", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
               { id: "8", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
               { id: "9", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" }
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++)
        $("#list1").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
    var lastsel2
    $("#rowed5").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        height: 250,
        colNames: ['ID Number', 'Name', 'Stock', 'Ship via', 'Notes'],
        colModel: [
               { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 90, sorttype: "int", editable: true },
               { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 150, editable: true, editoptions: { size: "20", maxlength: "30" } },
               { name: 'stock', index: 'stock', width: 60, editable: true, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "Yes:No" } },
               { name: 'ship', index: 'ship', width: 90, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;IN:InTime;TN:TNT;AR:ARAMEX" } },
               { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 200, sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: "textarea", editoptions: { rows: "2", cols: "10" } }
        ],
        multiselect: true,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
        pager: $('#pager2'),
        sortorder: "asc",
        viewrecords: true,
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            if (id && id !== lastsel2) {
                $('#rowed5').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel2);
                $('#rowed5').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                lastsel2 = id;
            }
        },
        editurl: "server.php",
        caption: "Input Types"
    });
    $("#rowed5").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', { del: false, add: false, edit: false }, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true });
    var mydata2 = [
               { id: "12345", name: "Desktop Computer", note: "note", stock: "Yes", ship: "FedEx" },
               { id: "23456", name: "Laptop", note: "Long text ", stock: "Yes", ship: "InTime" },
               { id: "34567", name: "LCD Monitor", note: "note3", stock: "Yes", ship: "TNT" },
               { id: "45678", name: "Speakers", note: "note", stock: "No", ship: "ARAMEX" },
               { id: "56789", name: "Laser Printer", note: "note2", stock: "Yes", ship: "FedEx" },
               { id: "67890", name: "Play Station", note: "note3", stock: "No", ship: "FedEx" },
               { id: "76543", name: "Mobile Telephone", note: "note", stock: "Yes", ship: "ARAMEX" },
               { id: "87654", name: "Server", note: "note2", stock: "Yes", ship: "TNT" },
               { id: "98765", name: "Matrix Printer", note: "note3", stock: "No", ship: "FedEx" }
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < mydata2.length; i++)
        $("#rowed5").jqGrid('addRowData', mydata2[i].id, mydata2[i]);
});
</script>
```

Comment: make sure you have included required jquery files in your page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have included these files in your page :-

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure the Jquery version you are using should be compatible with jqGrid version and the order in which these files will be placed should be the same as shown above,first include Jquery file and then jqGrid file.