# How to bind property on parent object with knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, computed-observable

I'm developing a application with knockout.js framework. I have one viewmodel like that:

```
var MyViewModel= {
    Id: ko.observable(),
    CountryCode: ko.observable(),
    NormalizedAddress:
        {
            COUNTRY_CODE: ko.computed(function () { return this.CountryCode(); }),
            Street: ko.observable(),
            ZipCode: ko.observable(),
            AreaCode: ko.observable(),
            Town: ko.observable(),
            Description: ko.observable()
        }
```

When I run my application, I obtain one exception like that:

> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property
>   or method 'CountryCode'

Can you help me to resolve my problem?

Thank you a lot,
Marco

Comment: What is `this`? Have you checked? It probably isn't what you think it is...

Comment: check similar questions, you maybe didn't include some script properly
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263635/0x800a01b6-microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or

Comment: I checked and this is the window object. There is a way for get the specific property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem using [subscribing feature](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) of knockout.

Now my code is like that:

```
var MyViewModel= {
    Id: ko.observable(),
    CountryCode: ko.observable(),
    NormalizedAddress:
        {
            COUNTRY_CODE: ko.observable(),
            Street: ko.observable(),
            ZipCode: ko.observable(),
            AreaCode: ko.observable(),
            Town: ko.observable(),
            Description: ko.observable()
        }
}

MyViewModel.CountryCode.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    MyViewModel.NormalizedAddress.COUNTRY_CODE(newValue);
});
```

So I can change the value when CountryCode property is changed.

Thanks